# GUI fullscreen and centered

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I'm trying to set fullscreen property to my GUI like that

```
set(gcf, 'units','normalized','position',[0 0 1 1]);
```

This doesn't work for me, my window isn't centered and there is a titlebar of matlab that appear above the GUI.

I've found many topic using this, isn't a problem of version ? I'm using Matlab R2012a,
Any solution for that?

Thanks !

ps: it's fullscreen but not centered

[image]

Comment: See if [`this file-exchange code`](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25471-maximize) is helpful for you.

Comment: I've found this function :

function maximize(hFig)
if nargin < 1
    hFig = gcf;
end
drawnow % Required to avoid Java errors
jFig = get(handle(hFig), 'JavaFrame'); 
jFig.setMaximized(true);

What I couldn't understand is that it works for a simple maximize(figure), but for my GUI, i've made maximize(handles.figure1) it doesn't change my display.

Comment: Maybe you need to disable all those commands that change the figure position, like the one you have in the question?

Comment: When I disable this command set(gcf, 'units','normalized','position',[0 0 1 1]); my window is well centered but, not in fullscreen mode.

Comment: That Java code should do it. If it doesn't work, my guess is that the GUI is programmed such that maximization is disabled. In that case, the maximize button on the window should not work either.

Comment: That's it, My maximize button is disabled and I found no solution to enable it, any tips ? Thanks !

Comment: @ranell, see my posted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, a figure window can be maximized by obtaining the underlying Java Frame object and calling its `setMaximized` method:

```
jf = get(handle(gcf), 'JavaFrame');
jf.setMaximized(true)
```

If this doesn't work, the likely reason is that resizing is disabled for that figure window. You should be able to re-enable resizing this way:

```
set(gcf, 'Resize', 'on')
```

Of course, replace `gcf` with the handle of the respective figure if it is not the current figure.

Comment: Great, it enable the maximize button, however, there's two other problem : 
-Could it be maximized when I execute the GUI ? The set(gcf, 'units','normalized','OuterPosition',[0 0 1 1]); doesn't works in this case
-The content of the window is not as well centered as in the GUIDE (should adapt the GUIDE instead ?)

Comment: I wouldn't use the OuterPosition property to maximize, but the Java Frame approach. Make sure you set Resize to on everytime, in case the property gets reset. – Regarding the centering: I suppose that is why resizing is disabled on GUIDE-generated GUIs by default. The GUI layout assumes a certain window size, if you resize nonetheless it may be broken. The only way around that I see is to program the GUI explicitly in such a way that it can adapt to different window sizes, probably using ResizeFcn for dynamic re-layout.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
set(0,'units','pixels')
screensize = get(0,'screensize')

fh = figure(....)
...

set(fh, 'units','pixels','Position', screensize);      %// without menubar
%// or
set(fh, 'units','pixels','OuterPosition', screensize); %// with menubar
```

The default units of the `'parent'` **0** is usually pixels, if you want to be sure not to mess up other functions add the following at the beginning:

```
defaultunits = get(0,'units')
```

and at the end:

```
set(0,'units', defaultunits)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, that displays me the same thing than set(gcf, 'units','normalized','OuterPosition',[0 0 1 1]);

Comment: on my machine the code works correctly. Are you modifying your window size another time in your code? Be aware that the 3rd and 4th value of `'Position'`are width and height of your figure.

Answer (score 0):

You were nearly right:

```
set(gcf, 'units','normalized','OuterPosition',[0 0 1 1]);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I've tried both, it returns me the same thing, not centered + titlebar of matlab

Comment: That's odd, it works perfectly for me, sorry I can't be more help.